# Notify close voters when a question receives three reopen votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

On sites with a lot of users it can be hard for a question which was closed to be reopened because the question gets pushed away and hidden from a lot of the common places people  find questions.

On smaller sites, there aren't many people around to cast reopen votes.

I close a lot of questions, and don't want to be notified about every little thing that happens (edits, comments etc).

However, I would be happy to be told a question which I closed is over halfway open again because this is not a trivial hurdle, and I'm likely to want to take a look.

Comment: No,they will vote to close again …then cycle repeats.

Comment: @Fawad they can't vote to close again within 14 days. Also they get this notification before it is open again so they can't close it.

Comment: after edit, the OP can ping anyone of the close voter in comments. Then if they casted a reopen vote, it will be pushed to reopen review queue (which is very less in count).

Comment: @SagarV I don't think the reopen queue works well enough - hence this suggestion. People who's questions are likely to be closed do not know you can @ping close voters`

Comment: The ping will work for all who is related with the post. edit, close vote (but not up & down vote and flag.) . at present, the review queue contains 109 reopen posts. sometimes, it will be very less than that. So, checking it is easy. **Anyway the requested feature will be helpful if implemented except some situations**

Comment: @SagarV I am aware of who I can ping, but new users who's questions are closed are not likely to know.

Comment: @SagarV [You can only notify moderators or gold badge holders who closed your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)—if 5 normal users vote to close, you *cannot notify any of them* unless they leave a comment as well.